# Extracting Values from Websites

Tags: html, vba, excel

I am trying to extract price from a website into Excel of a single barcode. So far I have found small pieces of code and tried to fit them together. The only success I had is getting the barcode into search box and then clicking. Then the website shows the result but I am not able to get that result from the website into Excel.

```
Sub GetPriceFromWeb1()

Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
Dim doc As HTMLDocument

Dim htmlInput As IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLButton As IHTMLElement

IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate " http://www.web1.com"

Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop

Set doc = IE.Document
Set htmlInput = doc.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolderDefault_mainContent_tabbedMediaVal_9_txtBarcode")
htmlInput.Focus
htmlInput.Value = "045986013729"

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")

Set HTMLButton = doc.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolderDefault_mainContent_tabbedMediaVal_9_getValSmall")
HTMLButton.Focus
HTMLButton.Click

'After clicking the button, the page refreshes and shows the barcode, title and price and shows a message (which disappears in a short time that item has been added)

Dim tag
Dim tags As Object
Set tags = doc.getElementsByClassName("col_Price")

For Each tag In tags
    If tag.className = "col_Price" Then
        MsgBox tag.innerText
        Exit For
    End If
Next tag

End Sub
```

The website has the following HTML Code for the values I am interested in extracting:

```
<div class="row rowDetails_Media">
    <div class="col_Delete"><span class=""><a id="ContentPlaceHolderDefault_mainContent_BasketContents_14_rptBasket_btnDelete_0" class="delete" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderDefault$mainContent$BasketContents_14$rptBasket$ctl00$btnDelete','')"></a></span></div>
    <div class="col_Title">Presumed Innocent </div>
    <div class="col_Items">1 </div>
    <div class="col_Code">0085391203421 </div>
    <div class="col_Price">0.05 </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

*The values I want are:*

1. The title in col_Title: **Presumed Innocent** in Cell B2 Sheet 1
2. The price in col_Price: **0.05** in Cell C2 in Sheet 1.

I would highly appreciate your help in this regard.

Comment: After clicking the button, try waiting again until the ready state is complete.

Comment: I have tried that as well, the question is regarding extracting title and price. thank you

Comment: `Set doc = IE.Document` - you need to do this again every time the page reloads: you are searching the previous page (and that no longer exists...)

Comment: @Tim Williams Yes, this is the problem, the code searches the previous page and it is still doing that even after using Set doc = IE.Document

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try...

```
Sub GetPriceFromWeb1()

Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
Dim doc As HTMLDocument

Dim htmlInput As IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLButton As IHTMLElement

IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate " http://www.web1.com"

Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop

Set doc = IE.Document
Set htmlInput = doc.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolderDefault_mainContent_tabbedMediaVal_9_txtBarcode")
htmlInput.Focus
htmlInput.Value = "045986013729"

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")

Set HTMLButton = doc.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolderDefault_mainContent_tabbedMediaVal_9_getValSmall")
HTMLButton.Focus
HTMLButton.Click

Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop

Set doc = IE.Document

'After clicking the button, the page refreshes and shows the barcode, title and price and shows a message (which disappears in a short time that item has been added)


Dim Tag As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim Tags As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim n As Integer

Set Tags = doc.getElementsByTagName("div")

For Each Tag In Tags
    If Tag.className = "col_Title" Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value = Tag.innerText
        n = n + 1
    ElseIf Tag.className = "col_Price" Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value = Tag.innerText
        n = n + 1
    End If
    If n = 2 Then Exit For
Next Tag

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. If there is already a scanned barcode, which is added to cart, your code gives me the title and price for that. So whenever we enter new barcode, the table gets updated and new row is added. I need the title and price of latest one, which is usually in the beginning of table. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Tim Williams Hi, where to put Exit for. Thanks

Comment: @StarShines I assume I answered your original question i.e. the part which was not working. This should give you an idea about the algorithm used in the code. If you have any further query, please close this question by accepting the answer and open a new question rather.

Comment: Thank you for your code and help. I figured out that table gets updated everytime an item is added using barcode, that's causing the problem.

Comment: That's because the values are being always written in B2 and C2. Declare a long variable (say "LR") to hold the next empty row available in column B and then use Range("B" & LR).value = and Range("C" & LR).value = in the code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. But the problem is not with excel table, I mean the price table on the webpage, as Tim said above, the code searches the previous page and not the new page even after using Set doc = IE.Document. Thanks

Comment: In that case, remove the counter variable n from the code and remove all the lines which manipulate the variable n and remove the line Exit For. This will give you the latest title and the price.

Comment: That didn't work. I just checked col_Price is css element